# Tab controls moving tabs between 2 monitors Winforms vs 2010

Tags: c#, winforms

Advice on approach needed.

I would like to give the user the ability to move tabs between 2 monitors.
What is the best approach?

1. Idea being user first load the form.
2. TabControls shows with eg 5 tabs
3. User can drag 01 tab on another monitor.

Is it possible?

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean something like Internet explorer, i.e. when you drag a tab out it creates a new window ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use some form of Docking container control.  Most of the commercial WinForms widget libraries have one, I have worked with Infragistics.  There are also free ones like this one [DockPanelSuite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dockpanelsuite/) (or at least free when I used it).  These docking controls will handle the transition between docking and floating, similar to the various windows you can drag around in Visual Studio (Properties, ToolBox, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

I would open two windows (one on each monitor) having a Tab-Control on each of them. The moving of a tab from one window to the other I would manage by using Drag'n'Drop.